# Persistent IP Routes

Tags: networking, rhel, iproute

I have the following static routes.

```
ip route add default via 10.160.65.1 table enp6s0
ip rule add from 10.160.65.5 lookup enp6s0
```

And I'm not sure how to make RedHat restore these rules on reboot. I created `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/routes-enp6s0`, but it doesn't restore after running `ifdown`/`ifup`.

Advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is a wrong file name.

Add routes to `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-enp6s0` file:

```
default via 10.160.65.1 table enp6s0
```

and rules to `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/rule-enp6s0` file:

```
from 10.160.65.5 lookup enp6s0
```